# Plurality of organizations

Tags: gramática, plurales

Spanish beginner here...

In one of my LinkedIn groups, a Spanish-speaking gentleman asked if there were any places you could learn to code in Spanish. I answered him "Codecademy tiene un sitio web en español".

Is that the correct syntax or should I have used the Ellos/Ellas/Usd. form "tienen"?

Comment: This is a good question. I believe the singular form is correct, but it may not be a hard and fast rule. For example, in American English, the singular form is usually used when referring to organizations (Codeacademy has...), but in British English the plural (Codeacademy have...).

Comment: That's what striked me as odd Flimzy, like how do Spanish speakers interpret the form of verbs in relation to organizations. There could also be a syntax variation between Latin and Spanish like you pointed out in the different English dialects. I'm excited to see the answers on here.

Comment: Also thank you for the title edit!

Comment: *Codeacademy* would be treated as a singular.  It's like the way this is usually handled in US English, as opposed to the way it's handled in UK English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could fall into the case of singular nouns that refer to plural (collective) things. Concordance rules can get tricky here.

From the "[Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=concordancia) (4.7)":

> Los **sustantivos colectivos** son aquellos que, en singular, designan un
>   conjunto de seres pertenecientes a una misma clase (gente, clero,
>   familia, rebaño, hayedo, cubertería, etc.) ... Cuando uno de estos sustantivos funciona como **sujeto**, **el verbo debe ir en singular**, así como los pronombres o adjetivos a él referidos: *«El rebaño se aleja definitivamente»* [...]   La concordancia en plural es admisible cuando se pasa de una oración a otra, pues en ese caso al segundo verbo le corresponde, en realidad, un sujeto plural tácito: *«La gente se acercaba y en cuanto veían la escena chillaban»*

In your case, I'd strongly prefer the singular form

> Codeacademy tiene un sitio web en español.

because we are mainly alluding to the organization as an abstract thing, not so much to the people who are part of it. I'd only use the plural form in other constructions, say

> Los [autores/responsables] de Codeacademy tienen un sitio web en español.